# C++ SDL on macosx without Xcode

Tags: c++, macos, g++, sdl

System: black Macbook running Mac os X 10.5.5 (Leopard)

I want to compile an SDL hello-world application using only g++. Xcode is good for macintosh but I want cross-platform compatibility, so I won't use any of the coaca framework (no menus, no buttons, etc). Also, porting Xcode projects to other os's is not something that sounds fun. I downloaded and installed SDL into /Library/Frameworks.

The big question is: what goes in the makefile (assuming just a helloWorld.cpp file in the source). I would like to avoid modifying the Helloworld file found [here](http://wiki.gp2x.org/wiki/Writing_an_SDL_Hello_World) if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took me a little while to figure this out myself, only I was already using SDL and was transitioning from C to C++ on Lion. Its not just the makefile that is the issue here, its probably your source file as well...

Download SDL-*version*.tar.gz

Extract and run at prompt

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/SDL && make && make install
```

Assuming everything actually built, you now can use the sdl-config to build your source by executing:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o Main `/home/user/SDL/sdl-config --cflags --libs` \
    -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa
```

which is the same as

```
g++ Main.cpp -o Main -I/home/user/SDL/include \
    -L/home/user/SDL/lib -lSDLmain -lSDL -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa
```

Now the key here is that you are using C++... for SDL macros to correctly replace your main, you need to prevent the C++ compiler from mangling you main function call. To do this declare your main like the following:

```
extern "C" int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
}
```

If you don't include the **extern "C"** stuff, C++ will change the name of your main function and SDL won't be able to automatically find it. If you don't use the **int main(int argc, char ** argv)** function signature, C++ will complain about type mismatches... so you've got to do it verbatim. (If using GCC, you exclude the **extern "C"** portion)

Chenz

Comment: +1 This really helped after hours of frustration I got a simple SDL program to compile with g++-4.8.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
all: helloWorld

helloWorld: helloWorld.o
    g++ -o helloWorld helloWorld.o `sdl-config --libs`

helloWorld.o: helloWorld.cpp
    g++ -c `sdl-config --cflags` helloWorld.cpp
```

sdl-config is a tool which should have come with your SDL install that outputs appropriate compiler and linker flags for when compiling with SDL.

Comment: The install only installs the framework and not SDL config, and installing sdl-config on macintosh is obscure.

Comment: @Kevin Kostlan: Sorry, I thought you had installed it Unix style. You may still want to if you want to make your build process more portable. I think with the framework you can just compile g++ helloWorld.cpp -framework SDL -framework Cocoa

Comment: -framework is not working either. I also compiled sdl directly (./configure; make; make install) but do not know how to set the environmental variables such as path correctly (so it still complains config is not recognized).

Comment: I think it just leaves the sdl-config script in the source directory. As for the path variables, make install should put the libs in your library path by default. How about g++ helloWorld.cpp -lSDLmain -lSDL -framework Cocoa ? If it can't find the libs try adding the flag -L/usr/lib or wherever you put your compiled sdl lib.