# Compiling C++ SDL on macosx

Tags: c++, macos, g++, sdl

I installed SDL2 on Mac OSX 8.4 following the guide here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473310

I had to change the prefix "/home/user/SDL" to "/Users/agargara/programming/SDL/" because /home is just a placeholder in OSX 8.4 ― there's no permission to make folders in that directory without a bit of hacking.

I was able to compile a test file with the following:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o main -I/Users/agargara/programming/SDL/include/SDL2 -L/Users/agargara/programming/SDL/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa
```

However, running gives the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /home/user/SDL/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/agargara/programming/SDL-tut/01_hello_SDL/./hello
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I assume this is because somewhere, the library is still trying to use the incorrect prefix /home/user/. What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Why not just put a symbolic link at `/home/user/SDL` ?

Comment: Thanks Paul, that might be one solution. However, the directory /home is deprecated so I can't make any files there without changing some settings. Fortunately I realised SDL2 needs to be installed into /Libraries/Frameworks instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, with a bit more fiddling I got lucky and answered my own question! Rather than compiling from source, I needed to download the Development Library for OSX and copy it into /Library/Frameworks/.

Once that was finished, the correct method to compile was simply:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o main -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2 -framework Cocoa
```